# FIX/FAST packet analyzer

Tags: data, market-microstructure, tick-data

I have a network dump of market data in the FIX/FAST format (transported over UDP). Are there standard pieces of software (similar to Wireshark) that will parse and allow for inspection of the key-value pairs of the payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using a native C++ implementation based on [QuickFAST](https://code.google.com/p/quickfast/), you can use the sample FileToMulticast to implement what you need. But if you are looking for a way do decode UMDF ( BM&FBOVESPA FIX/FAST) you must first take care with the UDP packages itself and re assembly the messages, before the decodification

Answer (score 2):

Try the [FAST Antenna Codec for Windows](http://www.b2bits.com/performance_lab/fast_antenna_codec/fast_codec_windows.html).  You need a little wrapper app that reads the UDP data from your dump and feeds the payload (i.e. sans IP/UDP headers) to the codec.